# Evaluate a function using a loop Fortran 90

Tags: function, loops, fortran

I'm stuck in a process where I need to compute the values of a function `f[x,y,z]` on a grid. Here I put how I wrote the program, only evaluating on a one-dimensional grid.

I wrote the program:

```
program CHISQUARE_MINIMIZATION_VELOCITY_PROFILES
use distribution
IMPLICIT none
integer, parameter :: kp=1001    ! Parameter which states the number of points on the grid.
integer, parameter :: ndata=13   ! Parameter which states the number of elements of the data file.
integer, parameter :: nconst=3   ! Fixed integer parameter.

integer i, j, n
real*8 rc0, rcf, V00, V0f, d00, d0f, rc, V0, d, z
real*8 rcr(kp), V0r(kp), d0r(kp), chisq(kp)

!Scaling radius range
rc0=0.0d-5      ! kpc
rcf=1.0d2       ! kpc
call linspace(rc0,rcf,kp,rcr)

!**************If I call like this, it works normal*****************
!CHISQUARED(1.3d0, 130.2d0, 0.12d0, 1.0d0, 1.0d0, 2.0d0, 0.0d0, 0.0d0, 1, !ndata, nconst)

!       **1.27000000000000       0.745818846396887**
!    Press any key to continue
!**************If I call like this, it works normal*****************

    !******* Here is where my problem is****************
    do j=1, kp
    rc=rcr(j)
    write(*,*) rc, CHISQUARED(rc, 130.2d0, 0.12d0, 1.0d0, 1.0d0, 2.0d0, 0.0d0, 0.0d0, 1, ndata, nconst)
    enddo
    !******* Here is where my problem is****************

    end program CHISQUARE_MINIMIZATION_VELOCITY_PROFILES
```

I use the module where I compute the chi^2 distribution, coming from a theoretical model...

---

```
MODULE distribution
IMPLICIT NONE
CONTAINS

! I define here the chi^2 function****
real*8 function CHISQUARED(rc, V0, d, alpha, gamma, chi, a, b, n, ndata, nconst)

integer i, n, ndata, nconst
real*8 rc, V0, d
real*8 alpha, gamma, chi, a, b, s
real*8, DIMENSION(ndata,3) :: X
open(unit=1, file="data.txt")

s=0.0d0
do i=1, ndata
Read(1,*)  X(i,:)
    s=s+((X(i,2)-VELOCITYPROFILE(X(i,1), rc, V0, d, alpha, gamma, chi, a, b, n))/(X(i,3)))**2.0d0
end do

CHISQUARED=s/(ndata-nconst)

end function CHISQUARED


!****Here I define the model function
real*8 function VELOCITYPROFILE(r, rc, V0, d, alpha, gamma, chi, a, b, n)

integer i, n
real*8 r, rc, V0, d, alpha, gamma, chi, a, b, z

if (rc < 0.0d0 .OR. d < 0.0d0 .OR. a <0.0d0 .OR. b <0.0d0 .OR. alpha < 0.0d0 .OR. gamma <0.0d0 .OR. chi < 0.0d0 .OR. n<1 ) then
    VELOCITYPROFILE=0.0d0
    return
    else
z=0.0d0
do i=0,n
    z=z+((V0*((r/rc)**(1.5d0))*(1+a+r/rc)**(-gamma*(2*n+0.5d0)))/((a+(r/rc)**alpha)**(chi/2.0d0)))*(((b+r/rc)**gamma)/d)**i
end do

VELOCITYPROFILE=z
end if
end function VELOCITYPROFILE
END MODULE distribution
```

!*****************END OF THE MODULE******************************

the data.txt file is of the form

```
0.24    37.31   6.15
0.28    37.92   5.5
0.46    47.12   3.9
0.64    53.48   2.8
0.73    55.14   3.3
0.82    58.47   2.5
1.08    66.15   3.3
1.22    69.39   2.75
1.45    74.55   5.
1.71    77.94   2.93
1.87    81.66   2.5
2.2     86.81   3.02
2.28    90.08   2.1
2.69    94.38   3.92
2.7     95.36   1.8
```

In order to get several values of the function `CHISQUARED`, I use the subroutine `linspace` to generate the partition of the 1-dimensional grid

```
subroutine linspace(xi,xf,jmax,y)
integer jmax,j
real*8 xi,xf,y(jmax)
y=(/(xi+dble(j-1)*(xf-xi)/(dble(jmax)-1.0d0), j=1, jmax)/)
end subroutine linspace
```

What happens is that if in the main program, I call the function `CHISQUARED` like this:

```
CHISQUARED(1.3d0, 130.2d0, 0.12d0, 1.0d0, 1.0d0, 2.0d0, 0.0d0, 0.0d0, 1, ndata, nconst)

   **1.27000000000000       0.745818846396887**
Press any key to continue
```

I get some finite value, like, I don't know, 0.7 or something like this. (I restricted the data file so the result won't be the one written, I just put 0.7 as an example). However, when I put it inside a loop as it is in the program written above, to get the values on the one dimensional grid, it gives me the error

```
  **0.000000000000000E+000 NaN**
forrtl: severe (24): end-of-file during read, unit 1, file C:\Users\Ernesto Lopez Fune\Desktop\Minimize\newone\chisquarerotationcurve\data.txt
Image              PC        Routine            Line        Source
chisquarerotation  0040B889  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
Press any key to continue
```

Can anyone recommend me what to do in this case? How to overcome this barrier?

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] and append optionally some specific version when necessary.

Comment: I will not edit the title again, it is not worth it, but it is preferred here not to repeat tags in the title. If you want to stress it is Fortran 90, you can add the tag fortran90. But actually, your code is not Fortran 90 specific, it can be any later version (Fortran 95, 2003, 2008...). Alas, it is not even valid Fortran 90 at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your error, you reach the end of your file.
When you call your subroutine once, it's OK but in a loop, your file is read multiple times. After the first iteration, your file is read until the EOF control but for the next iteration, the program can't read anymore because it has already reached the end of the file.

You need to use the `REWIND(1)` statement before `end function CHISQUARED`. With this, the cursor will be re-positioned at the beginning of the file. Besides, I think it would be better to `OPEN` your file in the main program and not in a function or subroutine to avoid multiple OPEN/CLOSE.

Don't forget to `CLOSE` your file when you are done dealing with it.

Comment: Thank you very much @Coriolis It is woriking now